# Create orders with Shopify API

Tags: api, shopify

I am trying to transfer an e-commerce website to Shopify and was wondering if anyone has had experience creating orders with Shopify API? There are some 3rd party apps that provide such a service but none of them are working properly in my case.

Comment: It would help if you state clearly what you've tried, and why it failed. Creating orders in Shopify with the API is very limited, so if you state your needs clearly, it will expose those limits quicker and easier so you don't waste your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can import orders to your Shopify store using this API call: https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/order#create

Answer (score 0):

If your a developer trying to do this you can just setup a simple, local run application, that would do this for you, I'm a developer but also run a Shopify website and do something similar with Ruby.

If you an end user the only option you really have is to hire someone to build a private app for you, depending on what excatly you need to achieve its not overly difficult.

If you want to learn yourself... https://vimeo.com/130247240

There is lots of help out there..

Comment: Thanks a lot. The video is really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

With Shopify API you can create customers and Orders, Here orders can be created through the API, but no payment information will be collected, and no transaction performed. You can mark the order with any payment status.
For details, you can check Shopify Orders API

https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/orders/order

Also, along with orders, you can import Customers using Customers API endpoints  i.e
https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/customers

And  also can update the Status of your newly imported orders to fulfillment using
https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/shipping-and-fulfillment